# Get Message Tracking Log Without CC

Tags: exchange, powershell

I'm trying to figure out how to track email sent one by one without CC-ing any group or user only single recipients.

I have this script but show all emails including CC, is there anything I am missing?

```powershell
$senders=Get-User -Organization xx | Where { $_.RecipientType -eq ‘UserMailbox’ -and $_.useraccountcontrol -notlike '*accountdisabled*'}
Foreach($sender in $senders)
{
Get-MessageTrackingLog  -Start (Get-Date).AddHours(-3) -ResultSize Unlimited -Sender $sender.WindowsEmailAddress |?{$_.RecipientStatus -notcontains "cc" -and $_.RecipientCount -eq '1'  -and $_.sender -notlike 'xx@domain.com' -and $_.Recipients -notlike "*@domain.com" } | select  Sender,@{N="Receiver";E={$_.Recipients}},RecipientCount,Messagesubject,TimeStamp 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `RecipientStatus` that you want to filter by only appears to be included on the `RECEIVE` `EventId`.

```
? {$_.EventId -eq "RECEIVE" -and $_.RecipientStatus -notcontains "cc" [... more code ...]
```

Comment: I found its `and $_.RecipientStatus -notlike "*,*"`

Comment: Then you are not just excluding CC, you would be excluding any number of other statuses.

Comment: thats fine I just need to track message not in cc just one to one